# Populate database with json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database, loops

I have a JSON String in a JavaScript var, how I can loop through JSON string to make script like this output?

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3', '$varN');
```

Is there is any direct way to fill a table from a json string?

JSON Example:

```
{"table":[{"id":"1","name":"David","nick":"falk","year":"20"},{"id":"2","name":"Mark","nick":"master","year":"50"},{"id":"3","name":"jhon","nick":"jx","year":"20"},{"id":"4","name":"Maria","nick":"beauty","year":"20"}]}
```

Comment: can u please give a json example

Comment: I edited the question to add the example.
Refresh the page, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assign a variable name to the json object

```
var table = {"table":[{"id":"1","name":"David","nick":"falk","year":"20"},{"id":"2","name":"Mark","nick":"master","year":"50"},{"id":"3","name":"jhon","nick":"jx","year":"20"},{"id":"4","name":"Maria","nick":"beauty","year":"20"}]};
```

Using jquery

loop over the variable table which have the property table.

```
 $.each(table.table,function(index, item){
    //INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3', '$varN');     
     console.log("INSERT INTO table VALUES('"+ item.id + "','"+ item.name + "','"+ item.nick + "','"+ item.year +"')");
});
```

take a look in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/628Cb/

Comment: I got an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
But I fixed: table= JSON.parse(table);
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the for loop to iterate over the array contained by the `table` object.

```
var p = {"table":[{"id":"1","name":"David","nick":"falk","year":"20"},{"id":"2","name":"Mark","nick":"master","year":"50"},{"id":"3","name":"jhon","nick":"jx","year":"20"},{"id":"4","name":"Maria","nick":"beauty","year":"20"}]};
 var arr = p["table"];
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var obj = arr[i];
    alert(obj["id"] + " "+ obj["name"] + " "+ obj["nick"]+ " "+obj["year"]);   
    INSERT INTO table VALUES (obj["id"], obj["name"], obj["nick"], obj["year"]);   
}
```